# how to show empty value for a int datatype in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to show empty value for a int datatype in SQL?

I have a case statement on an int datatype column to show empty for the values less than or equal to 0.

```
case when [TotalValue] <= 0 Then ''
 when [TotalValue] > 0 Then [TotalValue]
 End as [TotalValue]
```

Right now, case statement is returning 0 for any values less than or equal to 0. I expect to have them as Empty. Having 0 instead of negative value is not a correct result.

How to convert the record to show only empty?

Comment: You're mixing up numbers and strings i.e. mixing up data with display. You would normally do this in your front end where you convert your number to a string to display. Returning `null` would be the best thing you could do from the database.

Comment: @DaleBurrell, i am generating a report .. where .. less than or equal to has to be empty. Obviously we can do this in SQL. Just want the logic

Comment: Again, you would normally do that in your report render engine. If you want to do it in SQL you have to convert your number to a string i.e. `convert(varchar,TotalValue)` so that you are dealing with a single datatype in your expression.

Comment: Got it .. Thanks !!!

Comment: @goofyui But **DON'T DO THAT!** What Dale is saying is the normal and expect result from the raw SQL is to return `NULL` in these places. Your reporting tool should let you configure the column show an empty value rather than null, and that's the correct way to handle this.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn .. thank you .. that is very valuable tip. I am following .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is that `Then ''` is automatically converted to `int` value, which happens to be 0 for empty strings (try `select CAST('' as int)` to check).
The data type for ambiguously defined column (like yours) is determined from the [data type precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Unambiguously defining the data type of the column would resolve the issue.

I recommend trying to return NULL from the database, like this:

```
case when [TotalValue] <= 0 Then NULL
 when [TotalValue] > 0 Then [TotalValue]
 End as [TotalValue]
```

Most likely, your report engine will convert NULL to something like an empty string. In addition, you may be getting some benefits of ability to manipulate numeric values, if your report engine supports those (e.g. calculate average over selection).

Alternatively, try casting the values to string in SQL:

```
case when [TotalValue] <= 0 Then ''
 when [TotalValue] > 0 Then CAST([TotalValue] as varchar)
 End as [TotalValue]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest construct is:

```
(case when TotalValue > 0 Then TotalValue
 end) as TotalValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always `CAST` the number to a `VARCHAR` (string) and then set it to an empty string when NULL:

```
ISNULL(CAST(TotalValue as varchar(10)),'') as TotalValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty string is a concept that doesn't make sense for integer datatype.

Generally you should return the results to the application as integer datatype and use `NULL` for this and have your application display null as an empty string if desired.

If you do need to do this in SQL you are now dealing with strings rather than integers.

One way of converting to string and [performing your desired formatting](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Jan/05/Blank-Zero-Values-in-CSharp-Number-Format-Strings) is with the `FORMAT` function.

```
SELECT FORMAT(TotalValue, '0;"";""')
FROM 
(VALUES (1),
        (0),
        (-123), 
        (123456))T(TotalValue)
```

Returns

```
1


123456
```